# Gitlab 7.8.4 unable to push with SSH or HTTPS

Tags: gitlab, git-shell

**Our setup:**
Gitlab CE
Gitlab 7.8.4
Git-shell: 2.5.4
Gitlab API: v3
Ruby: 2.1.5p273
Rails: 4.1.1

This is test is on a private repository owned by the same user that is trying to push to it (user is admin). Environment check is clean with no errors. Same error whether we try HTTPS or SSH. SSH worked before the upgrade.

Error:

```
git push -u origin master
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token at 'false' (JSON::ParserError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_access_status.rb:13:in     `create_from_json'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:34:in `check_access'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:25:in `exec'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:16:in `<main>'
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Similar issue: 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/838

It would appear that we have proper access via HTTPS and SSH, but something on the server, perhaps with git-shell is not right.

**What we've done so far:**

sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:setup RAILS_ENV=production

Made sure 'AllowUsers git' was in sshd_config

```
ssh-keygen -A
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: ED25519
```

Tried different version of git-shell back to 2.2.0.

```
# ssh git@gitlab.domain.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
Connection to gitlab.domain.com closed.
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of gitlab-shell/config.yml?

Comment: Ha. Okay. That's frustratingI never looked at at that. I had somehow introduced a typo in the URL when updating. Fixed that. All works fine.

Comment: Fixing the gitlab_url in gitlab-shell/config.yml is the answer to 90% of the questions on StackOverflow that regarding ability to push. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Geoff pointed out, my issue was a badly configured gitlab-shell/config.yml. Once the type for gitlab_url was corrected, we were able to push and pull without any issues with HTTPS and SSH.